# How to return rows in jquery, whose html tag value is null?

Tags: jquery

How can I check the value of `value1` for all the rows in the table, and return all the rows with value1 is null?

### HTML

```
<?  foreach ( $timelineaspects as $a ) { ?>
        <table id ='transaction_events' class="table-condensed ">
            <tr class ="selector " value1= "<?=$a['value1']?>"  > 
                ..........................
            </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Below is the jquery snippet, but it is not returning the null value- rows.

### jQuery

```
    var events = $("#transaction_events tr").each(function () {
        return $(this).find('value1').val() == ''
    }).closest("tr");
events.hide();
```

Comment: Use `filter`, `$('#transaction_events tr').filter(function() { return $(this).find('tr').attr('value1') == 'null'; });`

Comment: I need to check whether the value1 = null, then return the row.

Comment: If you need custom attributes (such as `value1`) you should go with [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attributes -> `<tr data-value1="...">`. You can then access them with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `value1` it is not a native attribute for the `tr` tag, you should use the `attr` method of `jQuery`.

The way you can access custom attributes is the following:

```
$('#transaction_events tr').each(
    function() {
        if ( $(this).attr('value1') === '' ) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
);
```

In addition it is better to use the prefix `data-` before the `value1` attribute, in order to comform with the HTML5 Standards. By this the `tr` tag should become like that:

```
<tr class ="selector " data-value1= "<?=$a['value1']?>"  >
```

and the attribute call it will become like that:

```
if ( $(this).attr('data-value1') === '' ) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Also, in case you script `<?=$a['value1']?>` print's out a `null` string, you have to change my conditional check from `=== ''` to `=== 'null'`

Finally, in case you have follow my sugestion with the `data-` prefix, you can also access your attributes with the method `.data()`. In your case will be like that:

```
$('#transaction_events tr').each(
    function() {
        if ( $(this).data('value1') === '' ) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
);
```

I suppose this is the answer for the "how can I return the rows":

```
var nullRows = $( '#transaction_events tr[value1="null"]' );

// nullRows.remove();
// nullRows.hide();
// nullRows.attr('value1', 'new value');
// what ever you like ....
```

In addition, based on my previews code you can hide the rows by doing the following modification:

```
$('#transaction_events tr').each(
    function() {
        if ( $(this).data('value1') === 'null' ) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    }
);
```

Both options should work.

Comment: Thanks. The null check is working, but how can I return the rows, I tried  var events = $('#transaction_events tr').each(
      function() {
          if ( $(this).data('value1') === '' ) {
        
             return $(this).find('tr').data('value1') == '';
          }
      }
  ).closest('tr');  But this is returning the entire '#transaction_events' section.

Comment: What you mean `but how can I return the rows` ? What do you like to do ?

Comment: i need to hide the rows which are having null value for attribute value1

Comment: Check again my answer. I have append a new script at the bottom. Also if you think this answer solving you problem, don't forget to mark my answer as the answer ;)